# List of Azure Data Bricks clusters with useful info about cluster size

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-databricks

I Would like to list Azure Data bricks cluster inventory with useful data pertaining to it using PowerShell. Any leads?

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Databricks CLI](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/index.html) that can be used within Powershell, and more specifically the [Clusters CLI](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/clusters-cli.html)

It will allow you to run commands such as

```
→ ~/› databricks clusters list --output JSON 
{
  "clusters": [
    {
      "cluster_id": "1234-567890-johns123",
      "driver": {
        "public_dns": "12.345.678.901",
        "node_id": "59cc30ad02c25bb7a8757e20d03bd621",
        "instance_id": "ab07b198eae4e82d9d4c4f85addaaf6c",
        "start_timestamp": 14641398417,
        "host_private_ip": "12.345.6.78",
        "private_ip": "01.234.5.67"
      }
      "spark_context_id": 132049817401283947123243,
      "jdbc_port": 10000,
      "cluster_name": "cluster-01",
      "spark_version": "5.5.x-cpu-ml-scala2.11",
      "node_type_id": "Standard_DS3_v2",
      "driver_node_type_id": "Standard_DS3_v2",
      "spark_env_vars": {
        "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/databricks/python3/bin/python3"
      },
      "autotermination_minutes": 120,
      "enable_elastic_disk": true,
      "cluster_source": "UI",
      "state": "RUNNING",
      "state_message": "",
      "start_time": 17436797,
      "last_state_loss_time": 19158237,
      "autoscale": {
        "min_workers": 2,
        "max_workers": 4
      },
      "cluster_memory_mb": 129024,
      "cluster_cores": 36.0,
      "default_tags": {
        "Vendor": "Databricks",
        "Creator": "john@smith.com",
        "ClusterName": "cluster-01",
        "ClusterId": "1234-567890-johns123"
      },
      "creator_user_name":  "john@smith.com",
      "pinned_by_user_name": "1038471338747",
      "init_scripts_safe_mode": false
    }
```